# How to make terraform delete an EKS cluster including the AWS resources created by kubernetes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I use `terraform` to create an environment in AWS.
The environment also contains a EKS cluster, which integrates in AWS and creates some resources there. (For example an ingress will create an application load balancer or a route 53 record. Or a pvc will create a volume.)

What is a good way to make `terraform destroy` also delete all those depending resources?

Right now I only see [destroy time provisioners](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/syntax#destroy-time-provisioners) with some ugly shell scripts.

Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: As far as I know there is no elegant way of doing this. If you use `terraform-aws-eks`, then it will manage basically everything except for those incidentals like you mentioned e.g. ALB/Route53 provisioned from annotations on ingress by AWS LB Controller. I would love for someone to prove me wrong so I can incorporate the implementation in my modules.

Comment: If you are open to other option [eksctl](https://eksctl.io/) is a great tool for the job.

Comment: No easy way to achieve AFAIK, otherwise you can make changes to provider to add flags to the resource to avoid `destroy` provisioners. I’ve raised one such PR’s [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/15634). Until it’s merged by Hashicorp, one can build providers locally & host on their corporate private registries.

Answer (score 0):

If you use modules like https://github.com/DNXLabs/terraform-aws-eks-lb-controller for ALBs

And terraform modules for the ingresses along with defining your route 53 records in terraform.  It will be able to handle this.

Essentially you have to define all that in terraform or use destroy time provisioners to clean it up.