# dependencies to dynamically configured module in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-ingress

I am using `terraform` to create a kubernetes (eks) environment in aws.

To do that, I mainly use three steps:

- create the eks cluster
- connect to the eks cluster to install the ingress controller
- create application containing an ingress that uses the ingress controller

For the second step I have a separate module, which configures kubectl/helm provider with the values from the first step. (Guess that is the only feasible way, as the connection details dynamically depend on the first step.)

Now I want to make sure, that all the ingress setup is finished, before application starts installing.

In order to do that I tried to explicitly make the third module depend on the second module.
However that seems not to be possible:

```
╷
│ Error: Module module.apps contains provider configuration
│
│ Providers cannot be configured within modules using count, for_each or depends_on.
╵
```

How can I make sure that all the infrastructure components are completely installed before application installs?

Also I need to make sure that on destroy all ingress objects are removed before the ingress controller is removed. (Otherwise artifacts like load balancers will remain, which prevent other objects to be deleted clearly.)

Also this should be handled by some dependency that seems to be not possible.

What did I miss? How do I get create and destroy in the right order in that case?

Comment: When I setup similar, I used terragrunt dependencies as they don't have this limitation. You may be interested in this recently released EKS provisioning TF project from AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/bootstrapping-clusters-with-eks-blueprints/

Comment: Also as a side note, I would advise against doing your application deployment via TF. There are better purpose-built tools for managing k8s resources such as flux, argocd, and spinnaker

Comment: The error you got appears to be because of provider configuration explicitly defined in one of those modules & that’s conflicting with the combined/dependant module. `terragrunt` helps to solve this problem but even with `terraform` if you don’t define provider configuration default as well `alias`, it should work.

Comment: RE: "removing ingress objects" That was asked about five days ago, and there still seems to be no good solution for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71924733/how-to-make-terraform-delete-an-eks-cluster-including-the-aws-resources-created